# Initializing Timers in C

Tags: c, linux, timer

I'm running Linux and have this code snippets that I want to use to manipulate a timer in C that every 40ms triggers a function. So far I'm only trying to run the section that creates and starts the new timer. However I'm getting the following error:

```
/tmp/ccA7MbyS.o: In function `main':
server.c:(.text+0x69e): undefined reference to `timer_create'
server.c:(.text+0x6be): undefined reference to `timer_settime'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I comment those methods out the code compiles fine. Any ideas?

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

// This struct is created to save information that will be needed by the timer,
// such as socket file descriptors, frame numbers and video captures.
struct send_frame_data {
  int socket_fd;
  // other fields
};

// This function will be called when the timer ticks
void send_frame(union sigval sv_data) {

  struct send_frame_data *data = (struct send_frame_data *) sv_data.sival_ptr;
  // You may retrieve information from the caller using data->field_name
  // ...
}

// ...

// The following snippet is used to create and start a new timer that runs
// every 40 ms.
struct send_frame_data data; // Set fields as necessary
struct sigevent play_event;
timer_t play_timer;
struct itimerspec play_interval;

memset(&play_event, 0, sizeof(play_event));
play_event.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
play_event.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &data;
play_event.sigev_notify_function = send_frame;

play_interval.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
play_interval.it_interval.tv_nsec = 40 * 1000000; // 40 ms in ns
play_interval.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
play_interval.it_value.tv_nsec = 1; // can't be zero

timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &play_event, &play_timer);
timer_settime(play_timer, 0, &play_interval, NULL);

// The following snippet is used to stop a currently running timer. The current
// task is not interrupted, only future tasks are stopped.
play_interval.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
play_interval.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
play_interval.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
play_interval.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
timer_settime(play_timer, 0, &play_interval, NULL);

// The following line is used to delete a timer.
timer_delete(play_timer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is because you're probably not linking with the real-time library (librt): `-lrt`.

More information on [its man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html):

> Link with -lrt.

Comment: I've been struggling all day with this and the solution was so simple haha, thanks man.

Comment: @PatricioJerí Happens to all of us :) Glad I could help.

Comment: And `-lrt` is documented in the `man` page of `clock_gettime`... Please **read `man` pages** (e.g. type `man clock_gettime` in your terminal), they help a lot.